# Incentre of non-equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AngleBisector.html

In the diagram,why does it looks like the  internal angle bisector meets at the point of contact of the tangent on the incircle.....isn't this valid only for equilateral triangle

Comment: It doesn't, although admittedly $T_2$ looks a bit close.

Comment: Looks like I looked only at T2 hence the confusion.Thanks for pointing it out  as in my textbook , the representation is exactly like T2

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal angle bisectors meet at the incenter since any internal angle bisector from a vertex is equidistant from the two sides but,in general, they don't meet at the point of contact of the tangent of the incircle.